# oracle data insertion failure without any error

Tags: java, database, oracle, sql-insert

I encountered the problem of data insertion failure, and oracle does not report any errors and prompts.
In order to verify this problem, we performed a query after the data was inserted, but the data can be queried at that time after the insertion, and after a period of time, it can not be queried again. I guess there may have been some regression.
Since Oracle does not have any log alerts, I have no more information to provide.
How can we solve this problem.

Comment: Did you commit the insert?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COMMIT.html#GUID-6CD5C9A7-54B9-4FA2-BA3C-D6B4492B9EE2

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.